# how to control refresh interval to oracle views

Tags: oracle

I am creating an oracle `view` basically as a read-only summary of data from other tables. It is not necessary to update the view every time if there is any updates to associated tables otherwise the workload will be huge and a waste. It is better to refresh the view `every 5 minutes` and then the front end can receive the latest data that will be all.

However, how to setup the oracle view refreshing interval? Do we have to settle this constraints in `PL/SQL`?

Comment: Are you referring to a Materialized View?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, the views should be generated by queries to join/group from other tables.

Comment: I would suggest to read the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17749/refresh.htm#DWHSG8363)

Comment: To @OldProgrammer's point, though, there are two very different types of objects in Oracle, views and materialized views.  A view is merely a stored query. It stores no data.  When the view is queried, the query is executed. There is nothing to refresh, there is nothing to materialize.  A materialized view, on the other hand, stores data and can be set to refresh itself on a regular interval.