# How does materialized view work in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Assume we are develop an Oracle view that present a simple inner join of several tables, like this

```
CREATE VIEW V_ABC AS 
SELECT SUM(TABLE_A.a+TABLE_B.b-TABLE_C.c), TABLE_A.a,TABLE_B.b,TABLE_C.c
FROM TABLE_A
join TABLE_B on TABLE_A.id = TABLE_B.fid
join TABLE_C on TABLE_B.id = TABLE_C.fid
GROUP BY TABLE_A.a,TABLE_B.b,TABLE_C.c;
```

If `TABLE_A`, `TABLE_B` and `TABLE_C` are tables that always get tons of frequent updates(every second) that could affect the view as well. But it is not necessary to keep view `V_ABC` synchronized with all three tables immediately, but it only requires to get the latest result when user query view `V_ABC`.

Then here is the question, how or when the materialized view updates in Oracle?

1. Does the synchronization occurs immediately when each time there is data update to any of the joining table, or
2. We can customized to let the view `V_ABC` sync with latest results when only user query the view?

The question is raised for the concern to performance. It is a huge waste to get the view query to executed again to respond to any updates from any table, especially when the tables are huge and get frequent `CRUD` apply to.

Comment: a mat view will refresh when you tell it to.  Its not like a view that executes a query each time you want data.  You can refresh as frequently (or infrequently) as you like, but you pull the data from a "snapshot" table just like any other regular table.

Comment: You're conflating `view` and `materialized view` again (similar to yesterday's question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342931/how-to-control-refresh-interval-to-oracle-views).  They are two completely separate types of objects in Oracle.  You've posted the code to create a `view`.  Your subject talks about a `materialized view`.  And most of your question seems to be talking about the behavior of a `materialized view` but is talking about a `view`.  If you are talking about a `materialized view`, you'd need to tell us how that materialized view is set to refresh.

Comment: Thank you both for the enlightening... And thanks @Justin Cave you still remember me :). Yes now I know what is wrong in my question.